# How to pass JTextField from JFrame into another JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have two JFrame (JFrame1 and JFrame2) with two JTextField1 and JTextField2. My question is when I write "Hello world " on JTextField2 from Jframe2 and then click on OK button, I see "Hello world " on JTextField1 on Jframe1 class.

How can I do this? I'm sorry if this is a newbie question but I'm learning..

Here is my code:

JFrame2:

```
private JFrame1 jf1;
private void btn2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    jf1.setjTextField1(this.jTextField2);
}
```

Comment: Do you need JFrame1's textfield text to show on JFrame2's textfield as well? Meaning that, do you need both JFrame to be able to see each other?

Comment: can you post some more code of JFrame1 and JFrame2

Comment: Start by defining a interface which describes the functionality you want to expose (setText for example). Have your classes implement this interface. Pass a reference of the class (implementing the interface) to other, so when the ok button is triggered, you can pass the String to the other class via the interface

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) or [Producer/Consumer Pattern](http://java.dzone.com/articles/producer-consumer-pattern) to solve the problem.

The basic idea is, you have something that generates a value and something that either wants to be notified or consume the generated value.

One of the other prinicples you should take the time to learn is also [Code to interface (not implementation)](http://www.fatagnus.com/program-to-an-interface-not-an-implementation/).  This sounds stranger then it is, but the the idea is to reduce the unnecessary exposure of your objects (to unintended/controlled modifications) and decouple your code, so you can change the underlying implementation without affecting any other code which relies on it

Given the nature of your problem, an observer pattern might be more suitable.  Most of Swing's listener's are based on the same principle.

We start by defining the contract that the "generator" will use to provide notification of changes...

```
public interface TextGeneratorObserver {

    public void textGenerated(String text);
}
```

Pretty simple.  This means we can safely provide an instance of any object that implements this `interface` to the generator and know that it won't do anything to our object, because the only thing it knows about is the `textGenerated` method.

Next, we need something that generates the output we are waiting for...

```
public class GeneratorPane extends JPanel {

    private TextGeneratorObserver observer;
    private JTextField field;
    private JButton button;

    public GeneratorPane(TextGeneratorObserver observer) {
        this.observer = observer;

        field = new JTextField(10);
        button = new JButton("OK");

        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                observer.textGenerated(field.getText());
            }
        };

        button.addActionListener(listener);
        field.addActionListener(listener);

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);

        add(field, gbc);
        add(button, gbc);
    }

}
```

This is just a simple `JPanel`, but it requires you to pass a instance of `TextGeneratorObserver` to it.  When the button (or field) triggers the `ActionListener`, the `ActionListener` calls the `textGenerated` to notify the observer that the text has been generated or changed

Now, we need someone to observer it...

```
public class ObserverPanel extends JPanel implements TextGeneratorObserver {

    private JLabel label;

    public ObserverPanel() {
        label = new JLabel("...");
        add(label);
    }

    @Override
    public void textGenerated(String text) {
        label.setText(text);
    }

}
```

This is a simple `JPanel` which implements the `TextGeneratorObserver` `interface` and updates it's `JLabel` with the new text

Then, we just need to plumb it together

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                ObserverPanel op = new ObserverPanel();
                op.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED), new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)));
                GeneratorPane pp = new GeneratorPane(op);
                pp.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GREEN), new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)));

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
                frame.add(pp);
                frame.add(op);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: Observer]

Comment: I like your solution and I believe many will benefit from it. But I have a question for you. According to OP, both frames need to be able to update each other. So in this case, are you going to let both frames implement observer and observable at the same time (both frames become producer and consumer)? Since both needs to see changes from the other and both needs to notify changes for the other. Will the design be correct if we do that? Hope you can reply this..

Comment: @user3437460 Actually, I'd recommend using a `JDialog` for the second window and when it's closed (via the okay button), obtain the value to be displayed on the second frame.  But if required, a bi-directional observer pattern would be capable of updating both frames

Comment: How would the code of bi-directional observer pattern looks like in Java when there are 2 JFrames? Do you mind providing a solution if I ask a question on that? Anyway, thanks for replying. It is always good to see you around.

Comment: Well, it all comes down to needs.  For example, the second frame my require an observer which has a "add" method to register a observer with it or you might have a controller which sits between then which manages the relationship

Comment: Please note Observable is deprecated in Java 9. You can use PropertyChangeListener instead. Event though not used in this example, my search led me here...

Comment: @Miyagi Please note, I rolled my own - `PropertyChangeListener` is just a form of the observer pattern ;) - The answer was intended more as an example of the principle

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing there is actually sending the reference to the actual JTextField from one frame to the other one.

That's probably not a good idea cause both frames would be end up referencing the same visual component.

What you probably want is to keep all visual components separate, but make the text of the second text field equal to the text in the first one.

Something like this:

```
private void btn2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    jf1.getjTextField1().setText(this.jTextField2.getText());
}
```

Comment: TNk for your fast reply. I write it but it dose not work for me. I don't know why.
this is what I wrote:
private void btn2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        jf1 = new JFrame1();
        jf1.getjTextField1().setText(this.jTextField2.getText());
    }

Comment: Actually it set jTextField1 truly but I can not see it's text on GUI.

Comment: The problem is that you are doing "jf1 = new JFrame1();" inside the event. What you probably need is to already have the two frames already created in a window and have "jf1" referencing the first frame. Create the two frames when initializing the window.

Comment: your right. so, where i have to write "jf1 = new JFrame1();"?

Comment: Sorry I did not do yet.

Comment: Personally, I would avoid exposing components as public, as this encourages mis/unintended use

Comment: Yes. Finally I change Jframe2's variables to public.

Answer (score 1):

This is a complete working example I just coded out:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class FrameRunner
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyFrame f1 = new MyFrame("Frame 1");
        MyFrame f2 = new MyFrame("Frame 2");

        f1.addRef(f2);
        f2.addRef(f1);                  
    }       
}

class MyFrame extends JFrame{

    JTextField txt = new JTextField(8);
    JButton btn = new JButton("Send");
    MyFrame f = null;   

    public MyFrame(String title){
        super(title);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        setVisible(true);
        add(btn);
        add(txt);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        init();         
    }

    public void addRef(MyFrame f){
        this.f = f; 
    }

    public void init(){
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                f.update(txt.getText());
            }
        });     
    }

    public void update(String str){
        txt.setText(str);
    }   
}
```

In order to make the code short and easier for you to understand. Many of the things I did not following the conventions and I did not modularize the codes. But this should give you a very good idea of how you can pass in the reference of another `JFrame`.

This code shows an example of how `Frame1` has a reference on `Frame2`. Yet `Frame2` also has a reference on `Frame1`.

Whatever things you type in `JFrame1` can be send to `JFrame2's` `textfield`. Same for the other way round.

Comment: @Arashm You are welcome ;)  Just make sure you don't accept someone else's answer, else my `tick` will be removed. ;p

Comment: @arashm Unless another answer presents a better solution of course ;)

Comment: So, problems: extending from JFrame, not really recommended; not initialising the UI from with the EDT, will be waiting for more problems from the op on that later; exposing an entire class to another, where the functionality of the class isn't required to complete the task, the frames don't need to know about each other in the full, as this exposes your object to mis/unintended use by the other. An interface which defend the functionality which could be performed would be a better solution. While it might work, it's a bunch of bad practices that new developers should learn to avoid

Comment: eugenioy's answer work truly. for now my question is where i have to write "jf1 = new JFrame1();"?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I omitted a number of things in the code. In fact normally I don't extends from JFrame. most of the time I extends from JPanel and add it with a JFrame. I supposed OP should be able to deduce from the code how to pass the reference of specific components instead of the entire JFrame. Maybe you can post your solution as well? :)